# How to get around block of unknown apps when "unknown sources" is enabled?

Tags: installation

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab A and I want YouTube Vanced on the tablet. But it won't let me install it because it's an "unknown" app. 
Yes, I have enabled "unknown sources" and it still won't let me install the app.

A side note it's not blocking only YouTube vanced, it's blocking **all** unknown apps.

What can I do to get around this?

Here's a screenshot of the message:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: If you bought a pre-owned device, the device may be enterprise/work managed, see [View policies your admin is enforcing on your device](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7502354?hl=en) Check under `Settings > Security & location` for Managed or any indication that the device is under management.

Comment: @MorrisonChang can't be... I bought this tablet brand new from Wal-Mart

Comment: I also checked and it doesn't seem the tablet is being managed... Another thing to note though is that Google play itself seems to be blocking the installation because when I see all the tabs it says Google Play

Comment: Are you able to side-load install [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/). Just wondering if Google is testing ways of blocking YouTube Vanced as it gets around their ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned off Play Protect & went to `Settings > Security > More Security Options` and cleared the credentials and was able to successfully install YouTube vanced and other apps!